# Excel Variable Opens Outlook If I try To View It In Locals Window

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am trying to rename a copied worksheet in Excel using word VBA. When I try to set my worksheet variable to the new worksheet it tries to open Microsoft Outlook 2016. With each line after that (stepping through) it opens a dialogue box asking me to create a new Microsoft Outlook account.

The code does successfully create the copies of the template sheet but it fails to rename them.

** Edited to clarify the real issue and to add "Set oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Open(FileName:=WorkbookToWorkOn) 'Opens Excel" which was already in the workbook macro when the problem occurred.

```
Dim oXL As Excel.Application 'Requires loading "Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library" from Tools -> References
Dim oWB As Excel.Workbook
Dim oSheet As Excel.Worksheet

Set oXL = New Excel.Application
Set oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Open(FileName:=WorkbookToWorkOn) 'Opens Excel
oXL.Visible = True

For i = LBound(seller_names) To UBound(seller_names)
    With oXL.ActiveWorkbook
        .Sheets("Template").Copy After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
        Set oSheet = Sheets(.Sheets.Count) 'set worksheet to be the template copy
        If Len(seller_names(i)) > 31 Then
            oSheet.name = Left(seller_names(i), 31)
        Else
            oSheet.name = seller_names(i)
        End If
    End With
Next i
```

The line "Set oSheet = Sheets(.Sheets.Count) is where the open Outlook bug occurs. Both lines oSheet.name = run without generating errors but fail to rename the worksheet.

Comment: In which application is this running? You tag with Word... What I don't see is how you *get* the Excel application, using either `New Excel.Application`, `CreateObject` or `GetObject`. That could have something to do with the odd behavior... (although I would expect an error message, instead.)

Comment: Also, the first `Sheets` after the `=` isn't qualified. It would need a `.` before it to associate it with the workbook.

Comment: This is running in word vba. I do use New Excel.Application, I forgot to include that.

Could you clarify what you mean by your third comment?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by changing

```
.Sheets("Template").Copy After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
```

to

```
.Sheets("Template").Copy After:=.Sheets("Template (2)")
```